SFMC SQL query to pull records which are 90 days from today
I'm having issues with a SFMC SQL string which should get records that equal a date field  (Check_In_Date__c) 90 days from today. I don't want the records between today and the Check_In_Date__c, simply records that EQUAL 90 Days from TODAY. I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but I thought this was the correct query.
WHERE o.Check_In_Date__c >= GETDATE() AND o.Check_In_Date__c = dateadd(day, 90, GETDATE())

The = operator doesn't appear to work in this string, however all other operators work (>= and <=).
I've also tried the following strings and they are still not working expectedly:
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, o.Check_In_Date__c, GETDATE()) = 90


WHERE o.Check_In_Date__c = DATEADD(day, 90, GETDATE())


The issue might be due to the time component included in the GETDATE() function. To ensure you're comparing only the date part, you can use the CAST function to remove the time component.
Your query looks like this:
WHERE CAST(o.Check_In_Date__c AS DATE) = CAST(DATEADD(day, 90, GETDATE()) AS DATE)

This query casts both Check_In_Date__c and the result of DATEADD(day, 90, GETDATE()) to DATE, ensuring that only the date parts are compared.

Thank you, that worked perfectly! I didn't know you had to factor out time components here.
